# Custom 404 page being ignored in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, error-handling

I just cannot get custom error pages to work.

I've tried so many snippets from around the web.. but to no avail.

I've seen something about disabling the net 3.5 errors which override, but not sure if it applies to me.

in my web.config I have this

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="custom404.html">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="custom404.html" />
   </customErrors>
```

And I have an .html file there with code in within the root.

I just get the generic error 404 page.. content not found error. How can I over-ride it? Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Do I need to create an .aspx file instead of .html?

You can see this @ http://www.global-perspectives.eu/thisisnotarealurl

Comment: FOund one that works finally!

<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/custom404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>

within the system.webserver.. and remove anything from system.web